# Group acting on a Projective Space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions, projective-space

Let $G$ be an algebraic (zariski closed) subgroup of $SL(n,C)$ for some algebraically closed field $C$. Now $G$ acts on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $C$ where $V$ is a solution space of a linear homogeneous differential equation of order $n$ and is contained in a field, say, K (Picard-Vessiot extension). Induced by this action we see that $G$ is acting on the projective space $\mathbb{P}(V)$. Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be the basis of $V$ such that the basis elements satisfy a non-zero homogeneous polynomial $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with coefficients in $C$, i.e, $F(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=0$. Now does that imply that $G$ leaves a proper algebraic subset of $\mathbb{P}(V)$ invariant ? If yes, please help me in realising this.

I am stuck at this and could not realise this after some attempts. Please provide a small outline of the proof if this is true. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the connection between the $G$ action and the basis of $V$?  How is $G$ acting - presumably it's not just by random permutations on $P(V)$?

Comment: What does $F(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ mean?  Is this polynomial supposed to be evaluated in the symmetric algebra of $V$?  If so, then such an $F$ can never exist, since any basis for a vector space is algebraically independent in its symmetric algebra...

Comment: @JasonDeVito I have edited the question. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: " Let (v1,…,vn) be the basis of V such that the basis elements satisfy a non-zero homogeneous polynomial F(x1,…,xn) with coefficients in C" I don't understand at all what you're talking about. Do you have an example of what this basis is for, say, $V = \Bbb C^1$ or $V = \Bbb C^2$ ?

Comment: @mercio $V$ can be a solution space of the linear homogeneous differential equation, say, $L(y)=0$ of order $n$ and the basis is the $n$ linearly independent solutions of $L(y)=0$. Now does this make sense ?

Comment: No this doesn't tell me at all how i'm supposed to multiply vectors together to check your condition for "the" basis. I would like a very concrete example of a vector space $V$, "the" basis v1...vn, and the homogeneous polynomial $F$ you're talking about, as well as a proof that no other basis of $V$ satisfies any polynomial relation. Anyway this has nothing to do with your actual question : the action of GLn on P(V) is transitive so the only invariant subsets are P(V) and the empty set.

Comment: @mercio I would be really thankful if you could explain me this statement in the following paper [link](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~singer/papers/fano.pdf ) refer p.126

Comment: well the paper is not about the group GLn, but about a possibly much smaller group.

Comment: @mercio yes the group is  an algebraic subgroup of SL(n,C)

Comment: The question as written makes no sense. It is clear from the link you gave that the actual question you are supposed to ask is very different. (The group appearing in the proof of Fano's theorem is a certain Galois group, not some random subgroup of $GL(V)$ and definitely not the entire $GL(V)$.) Currently you are simply wasting the bounty. My suggestion is that you look closely at the paper you are reading and ask a better question, which would involve a considerable background information, defining the field $K$, the group $G$ etc.

Comment: @MorganRodgers $F$ is a non-zero homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables.

Comment: @MorganRodgers No. I have edited the question. I think it was vaguely written. Now does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

It follows from linear algebra that $G$ always acts transitively on $P(V)$. (For simplicity take $V=\mathbb K^n$. Given a one-dimensional subspace in $V$, take a non-zero vector $w_1$ in that space and extend it to a basis of $\mathbb K^n$. Then the matrix having the basis elements as columns sende the line spanned by the first vector in the standard basis to the line spanned by $w_1$.) So you see that there is just one $G$-orbit in $P(V)$ and there are no non-trivial invariant subsets. There is simple relation between $F(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ and $F(Av_1,\dots,Av_n)$, which would allow you to make deductions.

This corresponds to the fact that in $\mathbb R^n$ you can of course choose a basis of vectors of unit length, but this does not say anything about the orbits of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.